# Unable to set value from bean to JSP page

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-tags

Here is my code to set value in bean.

```
Infobean infobean = new Infobean();
Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

session.beginTransaction();
String query="SELECT ifnull(max(CONVERT(id, SIGNED)),0) as maxId FROM infotable";
List<?> list = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
int a = list.get(0).hashCode()+1;
String id = String.valueOf(a) ;
System.out.println(id);
infobean.setId(id);
```

Here I want to use that value in JSP page.

```
<td valign="top">
    <s:textfield  name="id" id="id" >
        <s:property value="%{id}" />
    </s:textfield>
</td>
```

In the above code, I was unable to set that value from bean.

Comment: are you sure the value is printed to the console?

Answer (score 2):

To display bean value in jsp you need to create bean instance in action class. Suppose `DemoAction` is the calss and `Infobean` is bean class having `id` property.

```
 public class Infobean {
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 }
public class DemoAction {
    private Infobean info;
    public Infobean getInfo() {
        return info;
    }
    public void setInfo(Infobean info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

Now you can display the property value as follows.

```
<s:property value="info.id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the value of the textfield because the value is populated from the `name` attribute for which you should provide the getter of the action bean. To set the value to the textfield other than provided by the `name` attribute you should use the `value` attribute. You can also set the value in the body of the tag but it's not recommended because it's first converted to string and then used to keep that string as value of the textfield. So, better for you is to provide the getter for the `name` attribute and/or `value` attribute. Struts2 has implemented MVC2 pattern and you don't have to write a controller for your actions. Instead you can provide the action class as a data model bean for your controller delegate. And because the action bean is placed by the framework on top of the value stack its properties evaluated in JSP by name to corresponding getters/setters without any prefixes. If you have nested beans inside the action bean and you didn't implement a model driven interface then you should provide getters/setters for these beans as well and use its name to dot prefix your bean's properties.

```
public Infobean extends ActionSupport {

  private Integer id;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception {    
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();        
    session.beginTransaction();
    String query="SELECT ifnull(max(id),0) as maxId FROM infotable";
    List list = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
    Object a = list.get(0);
    int id = Integer.parseInt(a.toString())+1;
    System.out.println(id);
    setId(id);

    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

**in JSP:**

```
<s:textfield name="id" value="%{id}"/>
```

And of course you should create a configuration in `struts.xml` to execute this action.