# set value of textfield in struts2 passed from previous page

Tags: javascript, html, struts2

Earlier I have created an HTML page that receives the data from the index.html file. This data is being assigned to the two text field in the insert.html page by using this code below.

```
      <label for="fname">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
      <label for="email">Email-id: </label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email">

      <script>
          var text = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
          var ar = text.substring(1).split("-");
          document.getElementById("email").value=ar[0];
          document.getElementById("fname").value=ar[1];
      </script>
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to assign the two textfields value in struts2 file by this js code or any other way?

```
      <s:textfield label = "Name" name = "name" id="fname"/>
      <s:textfield label = "Email-id" name = "email" id="email"/>
      <s:textfield label = "Mobile" name = "mobile" />
```

This is my index.html file code sending the value to the insert.jsp

```
<button type="button" id="push" disabled onclick="document.location.href ='insert.jsp?'+profile.getEmail()+'-'+profile.getName()">Enter data</button>
```

Comment: so when you try with the js code which you already have did you got any errror? what doesn't work ? Please elaborate

Comment: While in HTML page, the code didn't encounter any error and work as expected. Is the same code will work in struts2? Or how to do this same in struts2? @Swati

Comment: Moving from html page to the JSP and in Struts2 into the action is not easy. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22749195/573032) answer to learn more about flow of the action and setting values in the view.